# Ruby: Setting select model value not working via AngularJS binding

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation where I'm setting the object on a select element externally (an edit modal dialog). When I set the scope variable value the select control just loses it's value instead of selecting the equivalent item (like the object with the same id).

I wonder if it's a different ng-option value I need, there seem to many ways of populating it which I don't understand from the documentation. I'm using the basic type:

```
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors"></select>
```

I've created a similar situation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/krisg1984/nP7Vr/2/). I need clicking the button to set the proper value in the select drop down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularJS compares for reference rather than for equality. When you make that, AngularJS doesn't find any equivalent object in `$scope.colors`, and then sets the list to an empty value :

```js
$scope.setColor = function() {
    $scope.color = {id:12,name:'white',shade:'light'};
};
```

Instead, you can simply make that, like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nP7Vr/3/) :

```js
$scope.setColor = function() {
    $scope.color = $scope.colors[1];  
};
```

Comment: Yep! That was it.
I'm using jquery grep to lookup based on id in the array now.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/