# Set an already existing selected attribute to the default selected value in a select box Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I'm writing an Angular.js application which has a person object and within that person object there is an attribute for the person's state. See sample object:

```
{
    "name":"John Doe",
    "address":"555 Test Avenue",
    "city":"Some City",
    "state":{
        "code":"AZ",
        "name":"Arizona"
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, in my select, I am listing all the states. See below:

```
<select ng-options="state.name for state in states" ng-model="person.state"></select>
```

So what I think should be happening is that, since the person already has a state assigned to them, I want the default selected option in the `<select>` to be the person's state. I would have thought, since the `ng-model` is set to `person.state` that it would select that state by default, but it doesn't. Anyone know how to make it so it would? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178826/ruby-setting-select-model-value-not-working-via-angularjs-binding.

Comment: That was it Blackhole! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Blackhole for pointing me in the direction of the answer:

Angular compares for reference rather than for equality. All I had to do was find the index of the correct state in the states array and set the `person.state` object to reference THAT state object in the array. Now it works great! Thanks Blackhole for steering me in the right direction!